# Extracting images from scanned image

Tags: scanning

I scanned a few hundred photos from old photo albums. To make this more efficient I scanned multiple images simultaneously.

This looks now like this:

[image]

Is there an efficient way to extract those 6 images into separate files?

Comment: Windows, i'm using the maximum resultution of my Canon PIXMA MG6320 i cant improve anymore, i need a batch job i have about 100 of those 6in1 images

Comment: ok but the scanning is already done

Comment: I came across this for you https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/automator-for-windows/\

Comment: Also have a look at this as its open source and maybe completely free. Similar to the Automator in Mac, it learns your keystrokes and then automates from thereon. Meaning, you may to do one complete 6-1 image while the utility records your keystrokes, then it will repeat this for the remaining 99 sheets. thats the idea anyway!http://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who are too lazy to use Gimp or Photoshop, HP offers the HP Scan app, which I know at least works with the HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP M277dw, and uses OCR to recognize individual images on the flatbed. If you select Page Size, you can change Entire Scan Area to autodetect, and scan multiple photographs at the same time!

[image: Screenshot of the HP Windows App]

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Just be sure that:

- the background is clearly distinguishable from the photos. For 'white/high-key' photos you can use a carefully chosen dark backdrop.
- Also, be sure that the photos do not overlap
- (highly recommended) take care to not (accidentally) rotate too much the photos on the scanner's glass

You can use [Photoshop and/or Gimp](http://francoismalan.com/2013/01/how-to-batch-separate-crop-multiple-scanned-photos/) - perhaps [sometimes some adjustments will be needed after](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-editing/crop-straighten/). Be sure to have enough memory: each cropped image is opened in a separate window.

Also, if you're a real geek, you can use [ImageMagick](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/) for more horsepower but it won't be too user friendly at the beginning.